# Designing a Sqrt function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a bit of an academic exercise. I'm implementing a sqrt function in Python. Here's my code,

```
def mySqrt(x):
    low, high = 1, x
    while low < high:
        mid = low + (high - low)/2
        if mid * mid > x:
            high = mid - 1
        elif mid * mid < x:
            low = mid
        else:
            return mid
    return low
```

The issue is that this doesn't work when the number isn't a perfect square.
I want to redesign this function still using the log n complexity which would return the value of the sqrt to a specified number of decimal places.
So it's something like,

```
def sqrt(num, param):
    pass
```

thus

```
sqrt(5, 2) = 2.41
sqrt(5, 3) = 2.414
```

Can someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Taylor series to the rescue?

Comment: The fact that you can only calculate perfect squares is because you're only considering whole numbers. Identify what part of your code is responsible for that and you will know where to go.

Comment: your code considers only roundoff values or decimal values not the float values.

Comment: "this doesn't work when the number isn't a perfect square" So you need to look at the error of your current approximation, eg `m2 = mid * mid; err = abs(m2 - x)`. BTW, try to avoid calculating the same value multiple times, if you need `mid * mid` more than once, calculate it once and save it. But I strongly suggest that you use the Babylonian method: once it starts converging the number of correct bits doubles on every loop, whereas a bisection algorithm can only add one additional correct bit per loop.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).

```
def sqrt(x):
    n = 1
    for _ in range(10):
        print(n)
        n = (n + x/n) * 0.5
```

It converges extremely fast. Here's an example for `sqrt(2)`:

```
1
1.5
1.41666666667
1.41421568627
1.41421356237
1.41421356237
1.41421356237
1.41421356237
1.41421356237
1.41421356237
```

for `sqrt(3)`:

```
1
2.0
1.75
1.73214285714
1.73205081001
1.73205080757
1.73205080757
1.73205080757
1.73205080757
1.73205080757
```

Now you just need to replace the `for` loop with a `while` and a precision condition and return the result instead of just printing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find square root

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def ntsqrt(n):
    sgn = 0
    if n < 0:
        sgn = -1
        n = -n
    val = n
    while True:
        last = val
        val = (val + n / val) * 0.5
        if abs(val - last) < 1e-9:
            break
    if sgn < 0:
        return complex(0, val)
    return val

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ntsqrt(25.0)
```

The above prints successfully the exact square root 5.0 and the values for each iteration go something like this:

```
  5.00000000005
```

Comment: Sure, though Newton's Method for square roots is virtually the same as the Babylonian method, aka Heron's method. Or you can compute the delta: `delta = (n / val - val) * 0.5; val += delta` to avoid doing the subtraction in the test.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sqrt(num, param):
    return float(str(num**0.5)[:param+len(str(num).split("."))+1])
```

You could do it to the 1/2th power

Comment: If you do this, you can just as well do `mysqrt = math.sqrt`. Somewhat besides the point IMHO.